# Is it possible to get the value of UIButton.layer.borderColor in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I press the UIButton I want to use the UIButton.layer.borderColor to change the color of the view background to that color.

If this is possible I'd love to know how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            button.layer.borderWidth = 2
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : UIButton){
        sender.selected = !sender.selected

        if sender.selected {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColor: sender.layer.borderColor)
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unexpected interface name 'UIColor': expected expression  
Use of undeclared identifier 'CGColor'

Comment: can you post your code with error in your question? . As it is in swift you will have to change the syntax if working in objective-c, for swift i have checked in xcode it is working fine

Comment: Ya it's in Objective C 
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColor: sender.layer.borderColor);

Comment: overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor : sender.layer.borderColor] try that

Comment: That's it, you are the man/woman, never came across colorWithCGColor : before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed!  You just need to import the QuartzCore header file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: ah slight misunderstanding, I have set the border color but this is the only reference I have to the color that I want to change the view background to